# Getting Baddevicetoken when built from automation platform?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apn

I'm trying to send push notifications to QA testers. Local builds on Xcode are receiving push fine. If I archive an IPA under development, thats fine.
But any build that goes through stampede continuous automation system will result in invalid tokens.

We've looked at build settings and the provisioning profile are correct. The bundle identifiers are correct. It's distributed under debug.
What could be the issue behind BADDEVICETOKEN when going through build automation platform?

Answer (score 0):

The build may be nonprod. But the distribution needs to be prod signed (I believe)

So you need to send PN to Apple's prod server, not development.

Development server: api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443

Production server: api.push.apple.com:443